# Signalr connection on layout and view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

so I have the following code on my layout page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var connection = $.connection.notificationHub;
    connection.client.onTicketUpdated = function (model, user, notificationId) {
        ....
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("Successfully connected to CoreHub.");
    });
```

which the action should happen on any page. So the notification can show up in the main bar. However I have another page lets say Index.cshtml that is loaded through the main layout.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var connection = $.connection.notificationHub;
    connection.client.onNewTicket = function (model, user, notificationId){
        ....
    };
});
```

Is there a way to not call start again? Wouldn't that create 1 connection for the onTicketUpdated and another whole one for onNewTicket? Can I not use the hub.start() from the layout.cshtml inside the index.cshtml?

This has been bugging me for a while and all my research I haven't found anything that has fixed it. There has to be some way to do this because making 2 different connections for 2 simple functions seems like major over kill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to share connection between two pages:

**Layout.cshtml:**

```
var connection;
$(document).ready(function() {
    connection = connection || $.connection.notificationHub;
    connection.client.onTicketUpdated = function (model, user, notificationId) {
        ....
    }
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         console.log("Successfully connected to CoreHub.");
    });
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    connection = connection || $.connection.notificationHub;
    connection.client.onNewTicket = function (model, user, notificationId) {
        ....
    }
    //$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //     console.log("Successfully connected to CoreHub.");
    //});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped and does seem to work. Do you know if there is a problem with calling onTicketUpdated on both layout and index? would it overwrite the one from layout or would they merge together and work properly?

Comment: Of course, they will merge together, because `Index.cshtml` is a part of `Layout.cshtml` via `RenderBody()` and `connection` variable is the same for both pages.

Comment: I was talkinga bout the jquery functions not the cshtml pages. Sorry if I explained that weird. So I would be able to call the onTicketUpdated in layout and the index.cshtml.

Comment: Do you want to register two separated onTicketUpdated handlers? If it is true, you should register only one handler at Layout.cshtml and then trigger custom event, on which other handlers will be subscribed.